# Can you use character codes in XML?

Tags: xml

I referenced this website: http://biega.com/special-char.html to aid me in adding special characters in my XML. But to no avail.

Here is what I am doing:

In my XML I have attempted to add special characters like such:

```
<inc_1c>
<Url>http://www.google.com</Url>
<Title>This is some content &#187;</Title>
</inc_1c>
```

When I go to the browser it displays a broken special char symbol: �.

Initially I tried:

```
<Title>This is some content &raquo;</Title>
```

No dice. Anyone have any suggestions?

**Update: I should probably mention, this XML file is working with an XSL file for styles... Then its being pulled into an .ASPX page and displayed there.

Comment: Are you displaying the XML directly in the browser? With a stylesheet? Using CSS, using XSLT?

Comment: Show the code of how "its being pulled into an .ASPX page and displayed there".

Comment: I think this is a custom combiner code our IT team put together, but here it is: <Company:ContentCombiner ID="module4a" XMLFile="default.xml" XSLFile="inc-4a.xsl" CacheEnabled="false" runat="server" />

Comment: i've got an XML that holds data, an XSL that structures the HTML and an aspx that "includes" the combined XML and XSL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding / adjusting the `<meta charset="">`, either `<meta charset="ISO-8859">` or `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: This is an XML file, can I add a meta charset to it? Currently the top looks like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> btw I've tried changing the encoding type.

Comment: Sorry @nthChild  I thought this was an HTML file... don't know why!  You tried changing the encoding?

Comment: I noticed in another comment that you are using XSL.  Have you set/adjusted the encoding in the XSL?

Comment: Ha! I was changing the encoding on the XML file, not the XSL... <-- N00b. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this behavior using Firefox or IE8:

```
<html>
<body>
&#187;<br>
&raquo;<br>
&#xbb;
</body>
</html>
```

All three versions work as expected.  I suspect your browser may not support Unicode, or the font it's using doesn't have this character in it.

Comment: @Jarrod: The image “http://vertigrated.com/images/xbb.png” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Comment: can't get the image to work, but it works for me as well displays what looks like a >> in a single character.

Comment: I'm checking this on FF4, IE7, on a windows box. The "encoding" type was altered (UTF-8, UTF-16 and so on) all of which did not fix the code.... I have no idea how to solve for this...

Comment: Are you using a non-standard font in your browser configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using &#xbb; ?

- 187 is decimal, bb is the same value in hexadecimal (hence the extra x)
- Got this idea from http://unicode.org/reports/tr20/

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it didn't work. As stated above I have changed the encoding type to all types I know, no dice...